# Take first letter of each word - power automate

Tags: expression, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to compose a expression to take the first letters of each word in a title to create an ID.
Preferably, I'd like to use only the first 3 or 4 words, not the entire title.

If I'm able to split into an array, then take the 1st character of each row, then join back up, that would work but im not sure how to do this and it seems long winded.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not as elegant as I expected it to be but here we are:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.